# hadoop eclipse plugin latest version

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I can easily find eclipse plugins for hadoop 20.1, however for 1.2, I cannot find the plugins so easily.  The best I have found is a page that tells me to git some source code and then build the plugin from that.  Does anyone know where to download any hadoop plugin for all releases including, especially, 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the src for eclipse plugin(hadoop-1.1.2) [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/). And this is the [page](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/) that can take you to the desired version.

HTH

Comment: I have this downloaded via subclipse into my Eclipse workspace, I need to build the jar...it seems to be failing, should I create a new question for that...this could go on

Comment: I personally don't have any problem. But it would be better if you ask it as a new question. You'll get better response.